# External IMAP service if your provider sticks to POP3 only?

Tags: windows-7, windows, email, imap, pop3

My email provider refuses to implement IMAP email service. They stick to POP3 and will not change it imho ever.

Is there any service which can emulate imap service? I want to attach some service to my email pop account. this service would pull all the email and deliver it to me (on all my computers) as IMAP email.

Does any such service exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up a Gmail account (many other providers offer the same functionality, I'm just familiar with Gmail) and make it *pull* in your POP3 mails.

[image]

Then, access Gmail through IMAP.

A *transparent proxy* does not exist to my knowledge.

Comment: I do not know what transparent proxy is :), but this gmail feature looks nice.

Comment: What happens if you reply to pulled email? Will gmail keep the email address of pop3 account or it will use your gmail address?

Comment: @joeeoj: Look slightly above the section I highlighted in the screenshot ;) Yes, Gmail can automatically reply with the email address the mail was originally sent to.

Comment: In this case, something that would just sit between your client and server and let you connect via imap to a pop3 server.